# How can I activate my Iphone 4 without sim and wi-fi?

Tags: iphone

I have an old Iphone 4 with iOS 7.1.2 and I lost the carrier sim which it is locked,and the wi-fi  connection don't works at all, how can I activate it to use this like an Ipod?  (sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

Get a sim don't activate it or use someone else's sim for a second. It's only locked to the provider so by a sim from that provider an no one else or borrow someone's who is with that provider or call that provider an ask them to unlock it

Answer (score 0):

call the provider to unlock it.
But you can use it without sim/wifi as an ipod: sync it to itunes in your PC/Mac, and put the music on it with iTunes.